# PhpStorm runs only local PHPUnit configuration. How to force it to use remote (Docker)?

Tags: docker, phpunit, phpstorm

**Env:**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- PhpStorm 2017.1
- PHPUnit 5.5.4 (remote)

**PhpStorm settings:** Languages & Frameworks > PHP > PHPUnit

- Interpreter: Remote Docker
- Mappings: <project root> -> `/var/www/html`
- Docker container: <project root> -> `/var/www/html`
- Use composer autoloader: `/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php` (detects PHPUnit version 5.5.4)
- Default configuration file: `/var/www/html/tests/phpunit.xml`
- Default bootstrap file: `/var/www/html/tests/bootstrap.php`

Also I have configured local configuration. Local configuration points to the same `autoload.php`, config and bootstrap file. Local config works well, but I need to run tests on Docker container.

When I run test from PhpStorm, it uses local configuration, and I can't figure out how to tell PhpStorm to use remote.

**Important notice:**

XDebug configured with the remote Docker interpreter and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Found that I had a local interpreter configured, so I've deleted it, and left only one remote Docker interpreter. After that, remote configuration became active and runs well.